# Yammer: get usernames with messages

Tags: yammer

I was wondering how I could get the usernames, etc. from messages using the API. Calling the GET messages API gives me all the info I need from the message, but I only get the userID. Because of API request limits, I can't afford to do another API request to know for each messages all the needed userinfo.

Am I missing something, or is this simply not possible?

Comment: Can you post the exact URL and parameters you're using ?

Comment: Sure: I use this API endpoint: http://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/5741341.json

Comment: As @MSTr said you can find the user's info in the references section of the response

Answer (score 2):

In fact, check the "references" part of the response and you will find the whole details concerning your user.

Comment: I dont see where that is?

Comment: @Mstr is correct all the information on referenced users can be found in the references section at the bottom of the response.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see where that is? This is my API response from yammer (for one message)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 544689850
            [sender_id] => 1507082247
            [replied_to_id] => 544673530
            [created_at] => 2015/06/04 13:03:09 +0000
            [network_id] => 355014
            [message_type] => update
            [sender_type] => user
            [url] => https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/544689850
            [web_url] => https://www.yammer.com/b-rail.be/messages/544689850
            [group_id] => 5741341
            [body] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [parsed] => Signed and Approved!
                    [plain] => Signed and Approved!
                    [rich] => Signed and Approved!
                )

```
        [thread_id] => 544673530
        [client_type] => Web
        [client_url] => https://www.yammer.com/
        [system_message] => 
        [direct_message] => 
        [chat_client_sequence] => 
        [language] => en
        [notified_user_ids] => Array
            (
            )

        [privacy] => private
        [attachments] => Array
            (
            )

        [liked_by] => stdClass Object
            (
                [count] => 0
                [names] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [content_excerpt] => Signed and Approved!
        [group_created_id] => 5741341
    )
```